# FormsAuthenticationTicket isn't storing UserData

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I'm relatively new to .NET and am trying to figure out FormsAuthentication. I've gone through a few different tutorials and every time I hit the same problem.  For some reason the UserData isn't being stored in the ticket.  When I setup a break on the ticket in the Global.aspx.cs the UserName is there but the UserData is an empty string and the Version is set to 2 when it is specified as 1. Another odd thing is that every authenticated user is allowed to access the pages in my Admin_Content folder when the web.config specifies that only Administrators can.

Login.aspx

```
UserFull user = ManageUsers.login(loginTemplate.UserName, loginTemplate.Password);
if (user != null)
{
    string[] roles = { user.role };

    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
        1,
        userName,
        DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Now.AddDays(30),
        true,
        roles[0],
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
    );

    string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(encryptedTicket, true);

    Response.Redirect("Admin_Content/Admin.aspx");
 }
```

Global.aspx.cs Application_AuthenticateRequest

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
        {
            FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = (id.Ticket);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ticket.UserData))
            {
                string userData = ticket.UserData;
                string[] roles = userData.Split(',');
                HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(id, roles);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main web.config

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  <roleManager enabled="true"></roleManager>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="AOTMP_Demo" loginUrl="Login.aspx"
    protection="All" path="/" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
<configuration>
```

Admin_Content folder's web.config

```
<configuration>  
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Administrator"/>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not do this... because it creates a new authorization ticket.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie();
```

Instead set the cookie explicitly

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
cookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration;
Request.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Then it will be available in the global.asax

```
var userData = ((FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Ticket.UserData;
```

Comment: `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` does exactly what it is supposed to and is appropriate for this situation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b(v=vs.100).aspx. The little hack you put together I've tested and it doesn't work at all for me and hacks are rarely reliable anyway.

Comment: @cjbarth, how do you set UserData with FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie?

Comment: @cjbarth: Its ***NOT*** a hack. That is _how_ you setup cookies when out-of-the-box options are not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(encryptedTicket, true);
```

To

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

I believe `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` is already calling `FormsAuthentication.Encrypt` internally, so you're probably winding up with a malformed cookie.